# Subtract smallest timestamp per group from every other timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as such:

```
   Iter    ID       Time
0   1      A      12:00:00
1   1      B      12:00:01
2   1      C      12:00:01
3   2      B      12:02:00
4   2      A      12:02:02
5   2      C      12:02:06
6   3      C      12:05:01
7   3      B      12:05:00
8   3      A      12:05:05
```

I would like to get the offset of each timestamp from it's minimum timestamp for that iteration.

For instance the column of "Delta" for this example could be

```
   Iter    ID       Time       Delta
0   1      A      12:00:00    00:00:00
1   1      B      12:00:01    00:00:01
2   1      C      12:00:01    00:00:01
3   2      B      12:02:00    00:00:00
4   2      A      12:02:02    00:00:02
5   2      C      12:02:06    00:00:06
6   3      C      12:05:01    00:00:01
7   3      B      12:05:00    00:00:00
8   3      A      12:05:05    00:00:05
```

My first thought was to use apply, but not sure how to do it on only groups of Iter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this with `groupby` + `transform` + `min` and subtract the result from `Time`.

```
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)  # if needed
df['Delta'] = df.Time - df.groupby('Iter').Time.transform('min')

df

   Iter ID     Time    Delta
0     1  A 12:00:00 00:00:00
1     1  B 12:00:01 00:00:01
2     1  C 12:00:01 00:00:01
3     2  B 12:02:00 00:00:00
4     2  A 12:02:02 00:00:02
5     2  C 12:02:06 00:00:06
6     3  C 12:05:01 00:00:01
7     3  B 12:05:00 00:00:00
8     3  A 12:05:05 00:00:05
```

I've used `pd.to_timedelta` to convert `Time` to a column of `Timedelta` object (for which arithmetic is supported). Skip that step if `Time` is already a `Timedelta` column.

Comment: @ayhan Ah, that's what it was. Perfect now, cheers (also, was editing the timedelta in before your comment)

Comment: Yeah saw that. :)

Comment: wow thanks! That was much more straightforward than I thought.